# Gmsh example t4.py unable to find t4_image.png, other examples run fine

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, finite-element-analysis, gmsh

Goal is to solve my previous question [Generate a mesh from my polygon geometry to iterate FEM for geometry optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78055800/3904031) by myself using Gmsh

I've installed [Gmsh](https://gitlab.onelab.info/gmsh/gmsh/-/tree/master) ([also](https://gmsh.info/)) 4.12.2 using pip on macOS 10.15.7 Intel core i5 with Anaconda Python 3.7.

I ran the first five examples t1 through t5.py and all work nicely except t4.

https://gmsh.info/dev/doc/texinfo/gmsh.html#t4

I get

```
Exception: Could not open file `/Users/davido/Documents/Gmsn/../t4_image.png'
```

**note:** A friend ran t4.py under Windows and Python 3.11.5 and it worked fine. Right now I don't have the option to move to a new computer/OS,  nor upgrade my Anaconda "just to see what happens".

I've added t4.py at the bottom of the question, it uses path specifications in a way I'm not familiar with (I'm more of a numerical person) and I don't know what `/../` means.

I can't find any instance of `t4_image.png` on my computer except one from a few weeks ago within Anaconda packages when I first installed Gmsh.

Since making holes in a mesh is EXACTLY what I need to do to answer the linked question, I would like to get this example working.

Error:

```
(base) davido@Davidos-MacBook-Air Gmsn % python -i t4.py
Info    : Meshing 1D...
Info    : [  0%] Meshing curve 1 (Line)
Info    : [ 10%] Meshing curve 2 (Line)
[lines removed]
Info    : [ 90%] Meshing curve 19 (Circle)
Info    : [100%] Meshing curve 20 (Line)
Info    : Done meshing 1D (Wall 0.00703093s, CPU 0.024232s)
Info    : Meshing 2D...
Info    : [  0%] Meshing surface 22 (Plane, Frontal-Delaunay)
Info    : [ 50%] Meshing surface 24 (Plane, Frontal-Delaunay)
Info    : Done meshing 2D (Wall 0.0233768s, CPU 0.084051s)
Info    : 785 nodes 1629 elements
Info    : Writing 't4.msh'...
Info    : Done writing 't4.msh'
Error   : Could not open file `/Users/davido/Documents/Gmsn/../t4_image.png'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t4.py", line 180, in <module>
    gmsh.fltk.run()
  File "/Users/davido/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gmsh.py", line 10032, in run
    raise Exception(logger.getLastError())
Exception: Could not open file `/Users/davido/Documents/Gmsn/../t4_image.png'
```

Original script t4.py

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
#  Gmsh Python tutorial 4
#
#  Holes in surfaces, annotations, entity colors
#
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

import gmsh
import math
import sys
import os

gmsh.initialize()

gmsh.model.add("t4")

cm = 1e-02
e1 = 4.5 * cm
e2 = 6 * cm / 2
e3 = 5 * cm / 2
h1 = 5 * cm
h2 = 10 * cm
h3 = 5 * cm
h4 = 2 * cm
h5 = 4.5 * cm
R1 = 1 * cm
R2 = 1.5 * cm
r = 1 * cm
Lc1 = 0.01
Lc2 = 0.003


def hypot(a, b):
    return math.sqrt(a * a + b * b)


ccos = (-h5 * R1 + e2 * hypot(h5, hypot(e2, R1))) / (h5 * h5 + e2 * e2)
ssin = math.sqrt(1 - ccos * ccos)

# We start by defining some points and some lines. To make the code shorter we
# can redefine a namespace:
factory = gmsh.model.geo
factory.addPoint(-e1 - e2, 0, 0, Lc1, 1)
factory.addPoint(-e1 - e2, h1, 0, Lc1, 2)
factory.addPoint(-e3 - r, h1, 0, Lc2, 3)
factory.addPoint(-e3 - r, h1 + r, 0, Lc2, 4)
factory.addPoint(-e3, h1 + r, 0, Lc2, 5)
factory.addPoint(-e3, h1 + h2, 0, Lc1, 6)
factory.addPoint(e3, h1 + h2, 0, Lc1, 7)
factory.addPoint(e3, h1 + r, 0, Lc2, 8)
factory.addPoint(e3 + r, h1 + r, 0, Lc2, 9)
factory.addPoint(e3 + r, h1, 0, Lc2, 10)
factory.addPoint(e1 + e2, h1, 0, Lc1, 11)
factory.addPoint(e1 + e2, 0, 0, Lc1, 12)
factory.addPoint(e2, 0, 0, Lc1, 13)

factory.addPoint(R1 / ssin, h5 + R1 * ccos, 0, Lc2, 14)
factory.addPoint(0, h5, 0, Lc2, 15)
factory.addPoint(-R1 / ssin, h5 + R1 * ccos, 0, Lc2, 16)
factory.addPoint(-e2, 0.0, 0, Lc1, 17)

factory.addPoint(-R2, h1 + h3, 0, Lc2, 18)
factory.addPoint(-R2, h1 + h3 + h4, 0, Lc2, 19)
factory.addPoint(0, h1 + h3 + h4, 0, Lc2, 20)
factory.addPoint(R2, h1 + h3 + h4, 0, Lc2, 21)
factory.addPoint(R2, h1 + h3, 0, Lc2, 22)
factory.addPoint(0, h1 + h3, 0, Lc2, 23)

factory.addPoint(0, h1 + h3 + h4 + R2, 0, Lc2, 24)
factory.addPoint(0, h1 + h3 - R2, 0, Lc2, 25)

factory.addLine(1, 17, 1)
factory.addLine(17, 16, 2)

# Gmsh provides other curve primitives than straight lines: splines, B-splines,
# circle arcs, ellipse arcs, etc. Here we define a new circle arc, starting at
# point 14 and ending at point 16, with the circle's center being the point 15:
factory.addCircleArc(14, 15, 16, 3)

# Note that, in Gmsh, circle arcs should always be smaller than Pi. The
# OpenCASCADE geometry kernel does not have this limitation.

# We can then define additional lines and circles, as well as a new surface:
factory.addLine(14, 13, 4)
factory.addLine(13, 12, 5)
factory.addLine(12, 11, 6)
factory.addLine(11, 10, 7)
factory.addCircleArc(8, 9, 10, 8)
factory.addLine(8, 7, 9)
factory.addLine(7, 6, 10)
factory.addLine(6, 5, 11)
factory.addCircleArc(3, 4, 5, 12)
factory.addLine(3, 2, 13)
factory.addLine(2, 1, 14)
factory.addLine(18, 19, 15)
factory.addCircleArc(21, 20, 24, 16)
factory.addCircleArc(24, 20, 19, 17)
factory.addCircleArc(18, 23, 25, 18)
factory.addCircleArc(25, 23, 22, 19)
factory.addLine(21, 22, 20)

factory.addCurveLoop([17, -15, 18, 19, -20, 16], 21)
factory.addPlaneSurface([21], 22)

# But we still need to define the exterior surface. Since this surface has a
# hole, its definition now requires two curves loops:
factory.addCurveLoop([11, -12, 13, 14, 1, 2, -3, 4, 5, 6, 7, -8, 9, 10], 23)
factory.addPlaneSurface([23, 21], 24)

# As a general rule, if a surface has N holes, it is defined by N+1 curve loops:
# the first loop defines the exterior boundary; the other loops define the
# boundaries of the holes.

factory.synchronize()

# Finally, we can add some comments by creating a post-processing view
# containing some strings:
v = gmsh.view.add("comments")

# Add a text string in window coordinates, 10 pixels from the left and 10 pixels
# from the bottom:
gmsh.view.addListDataString(v, [10, -10], ["Created with Gmsh"])

# Add a text string in model coordinates centered at (X,Y,Z) = (0, 0.11, 0),
# with some style attributes:
gmsh.view.addListDataString(v, [0, 0.11, 0], ["Hole"],
                            ["Align", "Center", "Font", "Helvetica"])

# If a string starts with `file://', the rest is interpreted as an image
# file. For 3D annotations, the size in model coordinates can be specified after
# a `@' symbol in the form `widthxheight' (if one of `width' or `height' is
# zero, natural scaling is used; if both are zero, original image dimensions in
# pixels are used):
png = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), os.pardir,
                   't4_image.png')
print('Hey! png = ', png)
gmsh.view.addListDataString(v, [0, 0.09, 0], ["file://" + png + "@0.01x0"],
                            ["Align", "Center"])

# The 3D orientation of the image can be specified by proving the direction
# of the bottom and left edge of the image in model space:
gmsh.view.addListDataString(v, [-0.01, 0.09, 0],
                            ["file://" + png + "@0.01x0,0,0,1,0,1,0"])

# The image can also be drawn in "billboard" mode, i.e. always parallel to
# the camera, by using the `#' symbol:
gmsh.view.addListDataString(v, [0, 0.12, 0], ["file://" + png + "@0.01x0#"],
                            ["Align", "Center"])

# The size of 2D annotations is given directly in pixels:
gmsh.view.addListDataString(v, [150, -7], ["file://" + png + "@20x0"])

# These annotations are handled by a list-based post-processing view. For
# large post-processing datasets, that contain actual field values defined on
# a mesh, you should use model-based post-processing views instead, which
# allow to efficiently store continuous or discontinuous scalar, vector and
# tensor fields, or arbitrary polynomial order.

# Views and geometrical entities can be made to respond to double-click
# events, here to print some messages to the console:
gmsh.view.option.setString(v, "DoubleClickedCommand",
                           "Printf('View[0] has been double-clicked!');")
gmsh.option.setString(
    "Geometry.DoubleClickedLineCommand",
    "Printf('Curve %g has been double-clicked!', "
    "Geometry.DoubleClickedEntityTag);")

# We can also change the color of some entities:
gmsh.model.setColor([(2, 22)], 127, 127, 127)  # Gray50
gmsh.model.setColor([(2, 24)], 160, 32, 240)  # Purple
gmsh.model.setColor([(1, i) for i in range(1, 15)], 255, 0, 0)  # Red
gmsh.model.setColor([(1, i) for i in range(15, 21)], 255, 255, 0)  # Yellow

gmsh.model.mesh.generate(2)

gmsh.write("t4.msh")

# Launch the GUI to see the results:
if '-nopopup' not in sys.argv:
    gmsh.fltk.run()

gmsh.finalize()
```

Comment: note: I've registered at Gitlab to post an issue but currently my  "...account is pending approval from your GitLab administrator..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since making holes in a mesh is EXACTLY what I need to do to answer the linked question, I would like to get this example working.

First, I found that if I disabeled `gmsh.fltk.run()` the script would end without error and the mesh would be written but not displayed.

I could then open `t4.msh` in the GUI later either started from command line or from a script and view it.

Then I discovered that the whole `t4_image.png` part of the example was *superfluous to the example's main function*, so simply choosing not to generate this optional static image solves my problem.

```
if False:
    # If a string starts with `file://', the rest is interpreted as an image
    # file. For 3D annotations, the size in model coordinates can be specified after
    # a `@' symbol in the form `widthxheight' (if one of `width' or `height' is
    # zero, natural scaling is used; if both are zero, original image dimensions in
    # pixels are used):
    gmsh.view.addListDataString(v, [0, 0.09, 0], ["file://../t4_image.png@0.01x0"],
                                ["Align", "Center"])

    # The 3D orientation of the image can be specified by proving the direction
    # of the bottom and left edge of the image in model space:
    gmsh.view.addListDataString(v, [-0.01, 0.09, 0],
                                ["file://../t4_image.png@0.01x0,0,0,1,0,1,0"])

    # The image can also be drawn in "billboard" mode, i.e. always parallel to
    # the camera, by using the `#' symbol:
    gmsh.view.addListDataString(v, [0, 0.12, 0],
                                ["file://../t4_image.png@0.01x0#"],
                                ["Align", "Center"])

    # The size of 2D annotations is given directly in pixels:
    gmsh.view.addListDataString(v, [150, -7], ["file://../t4_image.png@20x0"])
```

[image: Gmsh t4.py example with .png stuff supressed]